# Picking objects of a given type from a List

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `Type` object. I want to find every object in a List that is of this type. Is there something like `list.OfType<>` using a `Type` object? Or do I have to use it this way:

```
list.Where(obj => obj.GetType() == type) // corrected thanks to jmcilhinney
```

This will be heavily used in my application, so I need to find a solution that is as fast as possible.

Comment: list is already of some type right?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad let's consider the list to be of a generic type `object`: List<object>

Comment: It would be .Where, not .All just so you know (All returns a bool)

Comment: @AlexD, That appears to not use the "Type" class, which does not seem to be supported for OfType

Comment: @AlexD `OfType` doesn't apply to this problem, I've mentioned it in the question

Comment: You can do something like `typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("OfType").MakeGenericMethod(type)` and cache resulting method... But I don't see why you would want to replace current code with anything more complicated. Convert it to extension if you want look and feel of `OfType`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `Where`:

```
var items = myList.Where(item => item.GetType() == myType);
```

Comment: Even though this isn't an "alternate" solution (he just had the wrong function call) it looks like the only way to do it from my research.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `OfType<T>` in the case where you have the type stored in a variable.  Remember that, with generics, the type parameter is a compile-time constant.  Therefore you can't use a generic function by specifying `T` in a *variable*, which is not known until runtime.

To look at this another way, there are two possible variants of your function:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetOfType<T>(IEnumerable<object> list)
{
    return list.OfType<T>();
}

public IEnumerable<object> GetOfType(IEnumerable<object> list, Type type)
{
    return list.All(obj => obj != null && obj.GetType() == type);
}
```

To use the generic version, ultimately some consumer of the function is going to need to supply the type as a compile-time constant.

Comment: +1. You can use `TypeOf<>` with unknown type (like `typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("OfType").MakeGenericMethod(type)` and cache resulting method...) but it will likely be slower than iteration + comparison. If I'd write extension I'd just add one `OfType(IEnumerable this list, Type t)` instead of wrapping `OfType`...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov good point, I didn't even realize you could use reflection.  The return type would be "object", but that's (apparently) ok in this case since the point is just to filter.